# Mongodb : insert data in a collection depending on values of two fields

Tags: mongodb, insert

My teammate and developper is in hospital for a while. I am trying to do what I can by so far to carry on our project… Here's my issue.
I would like to insert data in a collection if : for each distinct value of field "A", the value "X" of a field "B" doesn't exist. The problem is that others values ("Y","Z") can exist on the same field "B" regarding the structure of the database. Other problem, the database has more than 600millions of object_id so not sure a $lookup works...

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca7422ed842e23f5ce8f760"), 
    "vehicle_id" : NumberInt(75), 
    "data_value" : "A", 
    "schema_id" : NumberInt(101), 
    "option_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "record_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "location" : "-", 
    "condition" : "-"
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca7422ed842e23f5ce8f765"), 
    "vehicle_id" : NumberInt(75), 
    "data_value" : "A", 
    "schema_id" : NumberInt(102), 
    "option_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "record_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "location" : "-", 
    "condition" : "-"
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca7422ed842e23f5ce8f766"), 
    "vehicle_id" : NumberInt(101), 
    "data_value" : "A", 
    "schema_id" : NumberInt(101), 
    "option_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "record_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "location" : "-", 
    "condition" : "-"
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca7422ed842e23f5ce8f768"), 
    "vehicle_id" : NumberInt(102), 
    "data_value" : "A", 
    "schema_id" : NumberInt(101), 
    "option_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "record_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "location" : "-", 
    "condition" : "-"
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca7422ed842e23f5ce8f76a"), 
    "vehicle_id" : NumberInt(102), 
    "data_value" : null, 
    "schema_id" : NumberInt(102), 
    "option_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "record_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "location" : "-", 
    "condition" : "-"
}
```

What I would like to do for each "vehicle_id" if the value of a schema_id doesn't exists to insert an object with "new_id","vehicle_id:(concerned)","schema_id:(which doesn't exists)","location:-","data-value:-","option-id:0","record_id:0",condition:"-". In my basic db example it would be to insert "vehicle_id:101","schema_id:102","option_id:0",etc,... Thanks in advance guys

Comment: So, for each document where `schema_id` doesn't exist, you want to create a new document?

Comment: Yes exactly but for the values of schema_id which don't exist for each vehicle_id

Comment: So more than one document can have the same `vehicle_id` then? If thats the case, what if one document with `vehicle_id` of `10` has a valid `schema_id` but another document with the same `vehicle_id` does not?

Comment: I have 500000 vehicle_id distinct and 3000 schema_id distinct. Each document is a vehicle_id,schema_id,data_value(it’s a field). So for some vehicle_id I can have 3000 documents with same vehicle_id value, and 3000 schema_id values different from 1 to 3000 and data_value value. But for others vehicle_id I’ve got only 2500 schema_id values (for example) so 2500 documents. I would like to insert datavalue:0 for the 500 schema_id values not existing on these vehicle_id. Is that clear ?